# Python Number Game

Tags: python

This is a piece of code that allows the user to choose a number and the computer guesses the number. However, when the computer is guessing it sometimes guesses the same number more than once. How do I stop the computer from guessing a number it has already guessed.

```
import random

print('This is a game where the user chooses\n' +
  'a number for the computer to guess.')

guess = random.randint(1, 50)

number = int(input('\n\nChoose a number between 1 and 50: '))

while guess != number:
    if guess > number:
        guess = random.randint(number, 50)


    else: guess < number
    guess = random.randint(1, number)

print(guess)
input('Enter to see the next number')




print('The computer guessed your number:', guess,'!')


input('\n\n\nPress enter to exit!')
```

Comment: you could use binary search when picking numbers this will also guarantee the computer finds a solution in `O(nlog(n))` (I think thats the complexity of binary search) this doesnt answer the question at all... thats why its a comment

Answer (score 2):

without rewriting other aspects of your game...

try this for not choosing the same number twice:

```
numbers = range(1,51)
ind = random.randint(0, len(numbers)-1)
guess = numbers[ind]
numbers.remove(ind+1)
```

`numbers` will contain only the list of *unguessed* numbers in the range to be guessed

(and won't take forever to find the unguessed number when you have a list of 49 *guessed* numbers!)

[EDIT] and from the comment below:

```
numbers = range(1,51)
guess = numbers.pop(random.randint(0,len(numbers)-1))
```

Comment: how bout just `guess = numbers.pop(random.randint(1, len(numbers)))` and get rid of the remove

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a cache of all of the numbers that the computer has guessed. Maybe using a `dict` or `list` or something.

However, this doesn't prevent the computer from guessing the same number (it just means it'll pick another number if it's already seen it).

If you want to NEVER guess the same number twice, you need to randomly draw numbers from a *fixed* set of numbers and then remove the number from the set. This guarantees that you will never pick the same number twice. However, depending on the number of candidates, this may or may not be a feasible solution (for example, if there are infinite number of possibilities).

Comment: You're right, each subsequent range of numbers never includes a number that was seen before as long as the range excludes the current guess. So @HankDitton's approach would guarantee this (or at least, it did)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are only keeping the last guess information and guessing between that and the max or min of the total range.  This will maintain the same approach but restrict guesses based on already knowing if its higher or lower then numbers already guessed.

```
max_guess = 50
min_guess = 1

guess = random.randint(min_guess, max_guess)

while guess != number:
    if guess > number:
         max_guess = guess - 1
    else:
        min_guess = guess + 1         
    guess = random.randint(min_guess, max_guess)
```

Comment: bah this is good (+1), but since you have significantly changed his guessing already I would put a binary search solution also ... just my 2c

Comment: @JoranBeasley I could, but I was trying to maintain what I thought he was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want real random numbers and you are connected to Internet? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/randomdotorg/

I suggest also playing with random.seed or/and random.choice(range(min,max))

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
print('This is a game where the user chooses a number for the computer to guess.')

guesses = range(1,51)
random.shuffle(guesses)

number = int(input('\n\nChoose a number between 1 and 50: '))

while True:
  guess=guesses[0]
  print "The computer guessed %d" % (guess)
  if guess > number:
    guesses=[x for x in guesses if x<guess]
  elif guess < number:
    guesses=[x for x in guesses if x>guess]
  else:
    break

print('The computer guessed your number!')
```

We'll store all possible guesses and randomize their order. Then we'll use information from the user to progressively eliminate potential guesses. We don't have to reshuffle or choose random numbers as we go because removing elements from a randomly ordered array maintains the "randomness" of the next element we'll pull from it.

While fixing the range on your `random.randint()` call would also resolve the problem (and in a cleaner fashion), the method I describe offers an alternative approach which is more general (say, for instance, if the user suddenly tells you that their number is odd).

Answer (score 0):

Since this appears to be the "greater than, less than" game, I propose that the issue can be resolved by *fixing* the logic used for the range supplied to the random generator.

The computer should never guess from the same range twice as any choice the computer makes will always be "higher" or "lower" or "equal" to the number being sought - *this information should be used to update the range of the next random number chosen*. The updated range *excludes* the previous random guess.

Using `number` in the random range selection is wrong because it is independent of the guess made; it is simply what is being sought. You probably want two additional variables, `minGuess` and `maxGuess`, that are updated each loop and are used to limit the range of the random values.

Try to play the game against another person - how do *you* quickly "guess" the right number? If you're playing for minimum "guesses", you'll always divide the range directly in half, but you can pick randomly *from the remaining range* like the computer does (or should).